# Drop down menus with wp_nav_menu or wp_page_menu

Tags: menus

i have some doubts on what i am actually supposed to use to create drop down menus.By just looking at theme twenty ten,i have ,

```
<div id="access" role="navigation">
              <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu.  The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used.  If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used.  */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </div>
```

In the comments its written **"If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu..."**

When writing the css for the drop down menus,does it mean i have to write one for the menus created in the apprerance->menus wp admin backend and one for when the navigation from the wp admin backend is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu..."

Means, if you do not create a nav menu from the `Menus` section in the back end, then as a fall back, `wp_page_menu` will be used ([Check the `fallback` parameter for `wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), it is set to `wp_page_menu` by default). It completely depends on how you implement it in your theme. You can use `wp_list_pages` instead of `wp_page_menu` as your fallback. The CSS you apply will be applied relative to the container class `menu-header`. You can use whatever class you want to wrap the menu.